# How to search image based on text in image in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, custom, image

I have lots of images that contains several texts in SharePoint Online such as follows:

[image]

Now, I have a form where I will enter the search text such as "brown".

I want this image in search result.

Is it possible? If yes then How can I do this?

I am ready for any custom solution.

Comment: I've never tested it but I was under the impression that this was already available in SPO: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Intelligent-Search-Discovery/Search-for-words-in-your-images-in-Office-365/ba-p/135703

Comment: Don't know but when I am searching the text "Document", the required result is not appearing. I have already uploaded the image with text "Document" last week. Do I need to enable any specific feature or do I need to configure something to make this work?

Comment: Here is office 365 road map. https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-roadmap. There is nothing like you mentioned in road map. Its like in OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

Text search of images is only supported in 3 cases that I can think of.

1. Use a supported image type like TIF. IIRC TIF images are recognized.
2. Perform OCR yourself on the image prior to uploading the image. Embed the Text in the image metadata.
3. Apply metadata to the image in a list/library column. In your example above, you could upload the image and have a separate column that contains the text.

Also, apps such as OneNote natively  index recognizable text and handwriting. In case that may be a solution.